# Prefix for three-way logic

Tags: prefixes

As a programmer I usually want variable names that makes sense. I now stumbled upon a variable that can take three different values, so called [three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic).

In this case I am trying to name a variable that can indicate:

-1: Only others companies

0: All companies

1: Only my companies

It actually exist a fourth case, no companies, which I'm not interested in.
For a standard boolean naming is easy, onlyMyCompanies, isOtherCompany etc.

Out of pure academic interest, what prefix (or suffix) would you use for a three-valued logic?

Comment: This seems more like a programming conventions question than an English usage one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about programming conventions, not English language.

Comment: I'd say it's a [**tri-state** variable](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tri-state+variable%22). I've often used the three values +1, 0, -1 in theoretically "binary" configuration flags to mean *set to ON, set to OFF, **not (yet) explicitly set to anything*** (where I invariably #define'd the values as TRUE, FALSE, NOTFOUND, or later on used names like that in ***enum*** definitions).

Comment: "Tri-state" is the old term for the concept.  Way back when, there were advocates for tri-state over binary as the standard internal mode inside a computer.  Never got very far, though, except in the odd memory chip where you could squeeze a hair more data on a chip that way.

Comment: If anything, this looks like _four_-valued logic to me, even though you are not interested in one of the values.

Comment: Tri-state is the word I use to explain variables in programming that takes - well three - states, so I agree with @FumbleFingers

Comment: The poster seems to be requesting programming prefixes like "onlyMy" and "isOther", *not* an English adjective which describes the logical situation more broadly. I don't think adjectives like "tri-state" are what he/she is looking for.

Comment: Do you mean *instead of **three-valued***...?

Comment: Aside.  Tri-state is commonly used in hardware to describe binary logic circuity that has a "third" hardware state, that of high impedance; hi, low, and hi-impedance (the output pin of the device is disconnected).  Fancy constructs in programming taking 3 operands are sometimes refereed to as trinary constructs.  In 30 years of programming I've never heard of a tri-state variable as such.  Doesn't mean it isn't so.  Just my experience.  Perhaps because we are so familiar with hardware we don't use tri-state in that way.

Comment: And to you actual question.  Variable naming is a real game.  If this variable form is common, ask your programming group for input.  No doubt the company subscribes to some scheme out there.  Look up "Hungarian" notation to dive in.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I don't understand the question, but you seem to have already used a perfectly conventional adjective to describe a three-valued logic, namely ***three-valued***.

This phrase is widely used by logicians to describe non-Boolean logics which have three truth values: true, false, and neither.

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) you cite gives the following variants: ***trinary***, ***trivalent***, ***ternary***, or ***trilean***.

Answer (score 2):

"Trinary" or "ternary", after the fashion of "binary" (which is more commonly the case) is the [accepted technical term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_computer).

Answer (score 0):

For Boolean variables, a pretty standard convention is to use "is" and "not" to specify the two options.

```
isMyCompany
notMyCompany
```

Once you get past the simple true/false logic, how you go may depend on the exact circumstances.

In your description of the three options, AllCompanies is a superset inclusive of isMyCompany and notMyCompany so how you chose to name it is probably different than what you might choose for an enumerated list if the value sets did not overlap. For example:

```
isCompanyA
isCompanyB
etc.
```

Wheras in your case you might want:

```
isMyCompany
notMyCompany
isAnyCompany.
```

and, as you mentioned, recognizing the possible future inclusion of

```
notACompany
```

The best rule to follow in variable naming in coding? Don't be lazy: take the time to make it descriptive, even if it does wind up with a longer name.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make statements like

> if isCompany(x) {...} else { ... }

because you'll have multiple cases.  So maybe you'd use a switch.

> switch companyState(x)
>
> 1: {...}
>
> 2: {...}
>
> 3: {...}

So I think you simply want *state* or something more domain specific. I don't think there's a general pattern because, well, there isn't a general pattern.

This isn't inherently 3-valued, it's n-valued.  But then again Booleans aren't *really* two-valued--they can be null/undefined/whatever, depending on your language--which is why you get "truthiness" in things like javascript, where 'false' can be false, 0, [], etc.  So *isCompany(x)* may actually be handled with something like:

> y = isCompany(x)
>   if( y==null ) { ... } else 
>     if( y ) {...} else {...}

The pattern used in isThing() is wonderful, but sometimes it even falls apart